# Variadic templates with const references

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates

My project uses custom allocator that constructs objects the following way:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* create(Args... args)
{
    T* object = // request "bare" memory
    // call object constructor
    return new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(object)) T(args...);
}
```

There is a class, containing const reference as a field:

```
struct A {
  A(const string& s) : str_(s) {
    cout << &s << '\n';
  }

  const string& str_;
};
```

But when I'm trying to create an object, I'm getting wrong results:

```
string* str = new string("some string");
cout << str << '\n';
A* a = create<A>(*str);
```

The output:

```
0x7fffc8004db4
0x7fffd5436050
```

I thought the const reference field (`str_`) should contain the same address, that has been given to construction machinery, but obviously it isn't true.

Why is it happen, and how to avoid it?

*Ofc, I can not help using custom allocators, it is mandatory, I wouldn't ask.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* create(Args... args)
{
    T* object = // request "bare" memory
    // call object constructor
    return new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(object)) T(args...);
}
```

All your variadic arguments will be passed by value. Hence a copy is being made. You probably want to use forwarding references:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* create(Args&&... args)
{
    auto memory =  // request "bare" memory
    // call object constructor
    return new(memory) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Prints:

> ```
> 0x111ac20
> 0x111ac20
> ```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59aa980caf69f1e3)

---

Again consider data alignment whenever you want to use *placement-new*.

Comment: I beg your pardon, maybe I'm missing something... Are there other condiderations about alignment than just allocating a block of memory of size `sizeof(T)`? Does `sizeof` not report already aligned size?

Answer (score 2):

The call

```
A* a = create<A>(*str);
```

creates a copy of `*str` and uses the copy to call the function since the function is declared as

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* create(Args... args) {...}
```

`a` has a reference to an object that is no longer alive.

Use

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* create(Args&&... args)
{
   T* object = // request "bare" memory
   // call object constructor
   return new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(object)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

instead.

Comment: Wouldn't perfect forwarding be better than taking by `const&`, and then copying those into the constructor?

Comment: @Rakete1111, yes, it would. Since I still work in VS2008, use of perfect forwarding does not jump out as the first thing in my mind :) :)